# Where is this six-sided die from

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

Gaming with my daughter's boyfriend, I noticed this die. I asked him about it, but his tl;dr was it was a found die, and he has no idea what it's for or from. Any ideas?

[image: D6 Faces 3, 4, 6]
[image: D6 Faces 7, 10, 11]

I do note that 3 & 4 are the average of a d6, 6 & 7 are the average of a d12, and 10 & 11 are the average of a d20. But other than that I've got nothing. Google has failed me... or I have failed Google.

Who knows where this die is from?

Comment: To be clear, these pictures are both of the same die?

Comment: Is no one else impressed a how perfectly OP managed to get the backdrops lined up for both pictures?

Comment: 3 & 4 are the middle two values of a d6, the average value of the die roll is 3.5. It doesn't make sense to present two values as the average.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems to be from the board game 'Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone', according to 
[this post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/boardgames/comments/9rca0k/harry_potter_trivia_game_special_dice/):

> I own the US/English version of the game. The dice numbers are 4, 6, 11, 7, 3, 10.

...in particular, [this picture](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/898646/harry-potter-and-sorcerers-stone-trivia-game):

[image]

Comment: Is it proper to answer what turned out to be a non-RPG related question?

Comment: It's fine to *answer*--as to what happens to the question itself... pondering.

Comment: Can this answer include a description of the game's role-playing elements? (I'd like to give the moderators an excuse to keep this question instead of migrating it elsewhere!) (And an outdated yet semi-related [Meta question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5550/8610).)

Comment: Yay! You found it!

Comment: @HeyICanChan I've never played it, but according to boardgamegeek it's purely a trivia board game with no RP elements.

Comment: Okay, how about adding ideas as to how to use this die in your RPG system of choice?

Comment: I can do that later when I get home. The owner likes the random spread to use as a fall damage die.

Comment: The question has been migrated to boardgames.SE. Just a heads-up.